# Using SharePoint for an appraisal/360 process

Tags: development, best-practices

We are thinking of using SharePoint 2010 for an appraisal/360 process. The workflow is simple.

- HR Create appraisal for users
- User fills it in
- Manager fills it in
- User accepts appraisal
- Manager accepts appraisal
- appraisal is complete

The problem I have is only allowing some fields to be accessible by some users. IE the user can not change the manager fields etc.

A user can only see their form. A manager can see all their staff forms.

The normal sort of appraisal setup.

**How would you go about doing this?**

**My idea is as follows.**

- Create a custom list to hold the appraisal information. Do not give any one access to list.
- Create a webpart that will create an appraisal item. This will set a field to the user name of the user. It will also have a field to set the manager.
- Create a webpart that the user/manager sees. This will return back list items where the user has been set as the user or manager. It will only return the field items the user has access to.

  - Depending on the sate of the form (held in a column) the web part will allow them to progress the form along.

I imagine I would use a WCF to post data back and forth from the webpart to the server. Mainly because I have more knowledge in this then with SharePoint.

Doing it like this I could still set events based on the state to trigger workflows etc to send out emails.

Does this sound a viable idea?

Comment: Do you have the ability to use InfoPath Forms?  You might find that the form contols and properties that you can use with InfoPath will give you create control of managing who can update fields by using separate views of the form you create.

Comment: Do all users need InfoPath 2010 or just the user creating the forms? Currentley we only have Infopath 2007. I could get signoff for a few Infopath 2010 but not for the whole company.

Comment: It seems to me that you are confusing views and security. Don't assume that because the user doesn't see the item in the page he/she is not able to access it. Also, privacy might be a concern in your case. Keep in mind that the site administrators will always be able to access all data.